# Cross Domain Ajax Request returning Error in Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, firefox, cross-domain

I have a cross domain ajaxSubmit in one of my views.

```
$(".FileUploadDiv form").first().ajaxSubmit({
    success: function (success) {
        var redirectUrl = "@(Url.Action("CreateRfp"))";
        location.href = redirectUrl;
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
        alert(error.statusText);
    }
});
```

This code sends the form data to another web app created for document management. In this app I have added the following in `Global.asax.cs` -

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","content-type");
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and on Firefox on my local machine. But on my client's Firefox browser, it gives an error.

Although I can see that the form data is received by the web app and saved, it still goes to `error()` and not `success()`. The `statusText` is just `error` and the `responseText` is empty.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved after I upgraded their Firefox from Version 7 to version 28.